# Error message: "Failed to start CTDB"

Tags: startup

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.2, with the extra support time (extra PPA upgrading). in three PCs: two desktop and one laptop.

But, in one of the desktop I started to see an error message in the starting time, before the main full desktop screen.

The error message is literally:

> [FAILED] Failed to start CTDB.

From the `var/log/ctdb/log.ctdb` file, I get this:

> 2019/06/16 01:18:13.703348 ctdbd[2013]: CTDB starting on node
>
> 2019/06/16 01:18:13.766558 ctdbd[2013]: Recovery lock not set
>
> 2019/06/16 01:18:13.766627 ctdbd[2013]: Failed to read nodes file
>   "/etc/ctdb/nodes"
>
> 2019/06/16 01:18:13.766636 ctdbd[2013]: Failed to load nodes file
>   "/etc/ctdb/nodes"

And... from the `systemctl status ctdb.service` I got this:

> ● ctdb.service - CTDB
>
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ctdb.service; enabled; vendor
>   preset: enabled)
>
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-06-21 13:19:20
>   -04; 16min ago
>
> ```
>  Docs: man:ctdbd(1)
>
>        man:ctdb(7)
> ```
>
> jun 21 13:19:17 jjpg-MS-7788 systemd[1]: Starting CTDB...
>
> jun 21 13:19:17 jjpg-MS-7788 ctdbd_wrapper[1958]: No recovery lock
>   specified. Starting CTDB without split brain prevention.
>
> jun 21 13:19:20 jjpg-MS-7788 systemd[1]: ctdb.service: Control process
>   exited, code=exited status=1
>
> jun 21 13:19:20 jjpg-MS-7788 systemd[1]: ctdb.service: Failed with
>   result 'exit-code'.
>
> jun 21 13:19:20 jjpg-MS-7788 systemd[1]: Failed to start CTDB.

What does it exactly mean?

Is it something extremally important?

How can I fix it?

BTW: To a "normal" home user (not industry/commercial networks, not programmer), Is it absolutely needed to have samba, CTDB and TDB installed?

Answer (score 0):

[It is part of samba](https://ctdb.samba.org/):

> CTDB is a cluster implementation of the TDB database used by Samba and other projects to store temporary data. If an application is already using TDB for temporary data it is very easy to convert that application to be cluster aware and use CTDB instead.

Check `/var/log/ctdb`. It should have the complete message.

There is a recent [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1335540) claiming

```
mkdir -p /var/lib/run/ctdb
```

fixes -a- crash of ctdb. It is a fairly harmless command but do match your log file with the one in the bug report.

That bug is a duplicate of another [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1821775). Comment #2 fixes it too but in a slightly different way:

> Changed
>
> ```
> /etc/init.d/ctdb pidfile="/var/run/ctdb/ctdbd.pid"
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> pidfile="/run/ctdb/ctdbd.pid"
> ```
>
> Then
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl edit ctdb
>
> [Service] ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /run/ctdb
> ```
>
> And it will work upon reboot as well. (/run is deleted every reboot)
>   Still seems to be looking for /var/run in the logs though.

Pick one of the two and do a reboot

Comment: The solution exposed in this answer didn't work for me, the error messages is still the same.

Comment: pity. Ill leave it here until someone finds something else that does work.