# Relevance of samba, CTDB and TDB

Tags: samba

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.2, with the extended support time life through additional PPA backports.

I am a home user. I'm not a programmer and/or network manager. I don't have any network here. I just use the computer to my personal work (music, audio and MIDI, record, edit and playback).

I wonder the relevance of samba, CTDB and TDB to my personal installation.

Can I uninstall all those apps?

Comment: ...duplicate:https://askubuntu.com/questions/1151371/error-message-failed-to-start-ctdb

Comment: I don't know what is "extended support time life" and how "additional PPA backports" are related to it. I don't think the three packages in question are installed by default, and you should be able to uninstall them the same way they had been installed.

Comment: I guess some software, I installed here, installed those apps. I don't know which one.